# Return result not in terms of hypergeometric functions

Tags: special-functions, summation

I'm trying to sum over

```
summand = (2^(-2 + n) (1 - t)^(-1 + n/2) t^(
 1/2 (-1 + n)) η^n (1 + t η^2)^(-n/2)
  Gamma[-(1/2) + n] Gamma[1/2 + n]^2)/(π n! Gamma[-(1/2) + 2 n])
```

from n = 1 to infinity. I do this with the command

```
sum = Sum[summand, {n, 1, ∞}]
```

This returns a hypergeometric function

```
(-1 + HypergeometricPFQ[{-(1/2), 1/2, 1/2}, {-(1/4), 1/4}, (
  Sqrt[1 - t] Sqrt[t] η)/(
  2 Sqrt[1 + t η^2])])/(4 (1 - t) Sqrt[t])
```

I'm wondering whether it's possible to do this sum without getting a hypergeometric function (similar to `ExcludedForms` for `Simplify`).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What other function would you like to appear in the result? Do you have any assumptions on the terms in the sum?

Comment: Even evaluating parameters, I still obtain a hypergeometric function.

Comment: So does Maple 2021.

Comment: Maybe it's not possible then. I was hoping it would equal dilogarithms and logarithms.